# inserting into more than one table : mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say we have v1, v2, v3 and v4 values of which, v1 and v2 are to be inserted into table t1; v3 and v4 into table t2.
we can usually do that using:

```
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(v1,v2)
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(v3,v4)
```

However, if we want to do that in a single  statement?

something like `INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(v1,v2), t2 VALUES(v3,v4)`

someone asked me to use transactions to achieve that, but i don't know if that works for MyISAM.

I am using MySql database.

Comment: Individual statements in MyISAM tables are transactional: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, only one table per INSERT statement: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

You could potentially change the engine to InnoDB with [ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html), but make sure it won't break anything:

```
ALTER TABLE t1 ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

One final possibility (if you're really desparate to use transactions) would be to *denormalize* the data--merge t1 and t2 into the same table. But I'd recommend InnoDB, first.

Comment: thank you. I'll have to change the engine to InnoDB and use transactions then. :)